# Does using a library like cats make upgrading to dotty more or less difficult?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, dotty, scala-3

If I use cats in my scala project, would it make migrating to dotty easier or difficult?
I'm not too sure of the ramifications of using a library like this and how hard it will be to eventually migrate over to dotty.

Answer (score 4):

Using any library at all will force you to wait until it is released for Dotty.

For many libraries it will be a smooth migration if they don't use type system intensively, some will have to make some adjustments to provide support for new types, and all macros will need a total rewrite.

AFAIR Cats are making preparations for Dotty (you can see that [they even have tests for it](https://travis-ci.org/github/typelevel/cats/jobs/705788829)). But there is also the rest of TL ecosystem and each part of it will have to prepare for migration individually (while depending on its upstreams).

Personally, I wouldn't expect to migrate to Dotty in production for the first half a year. I would give some time to library author to migrate and test their changes. For now some attempts are being made, but since, not everything is set in stone yet, some libraries prefer to wait till right-before-the-release before they start migration.

Comment: IIUC dotty can consume libraries compiled for Scala 2.13, except for macros. I don't think cats has any macros in their API.